# Access 2010 RT crashes on Access 2016 machine

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

Without giving notice an administrator changed from Win 7 64 bit with Office 2010 32 bit to Win 10 64 bit with Office 2016 64 bit on a certain machine.

Now, our production database application based on Access 2010 Runtime 32 bit does not work anymore, ALTHOUGH I installed the neccessary program and let the application start with A2010 RT.

I checked all references, if they are available and not broken (IsBroken = false), but cannot find the cause for the Runtime error which determins the program.

Any other ideas to detect and solve the problem??

Does deinstallation of only Access 2016 64 bit could bring the solution??
(I found out that deinstallation of any Office 2016 app is not that easy but will try it with Office Deployment Tool).

Thanks your help!
Michael

Comment: If there is a Runtime error, what is the exact error message?

Comment: No specific error at all, only something like "Microsoft Access encountered a runtime error and has to be finished" (translated from German). That's what it makes so much difficult for me to find the error. The code which is behind the button where it occurs is pretty simple: DoCmd.OpenForm "frmKunden"

Comment: A screenshot of the error (even if it is in German) may help, it shows the type of error.

Comment: Does your VBA code compile? Please post the code for open/onload event trigger of the form, *frmKunden*. Except for very subtle design quirks and newer data types, most Access apps should be runnable across OS's, bit/versions, Office versions.

Comment: Yes code has been compiled on dev machine as on customers machine I use accde. BTW I used the "old" program version which has been running in Win7 with A2010 RT for many years. So there was no change in the program at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, but it had nothing to do with Access versions 2010 or 2016 or 32/64 bit.

I made a change on a table in SQL server but did not refresh the links to the tables in Access and did not create a new accde.

The reason, why the error did not pop up earlier was most probably, because no user entered data into this tab. So I assumed that the error was due to the change of OS and new Access version. It was only a coincidence of some changes.
Sorry and thanks for your participation on this thread.
Michael